# Calendar.MINUTE giving minutes without leading zero

Tags: java, android

Hi all I am using below code to get android phone time, but it is giving me  minutes without zero if the minutes are in between 1 to 9.

for example:right now I have time on my device 12:09 but its giving me as 12:9

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int mnts = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String curTime = "" + hrs + ":" + mnts;
return curTime;
```

after above code I also try below code its giving same thing as above, minutes without zero before number it the minutes in between 1 to 9 . .

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = cal.getTime();
int mHour = date.getHours();
int mMinute = date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: How can minutes be possibly given with a trailing zero as they are given as integers? It's your task to display them as you like.

Answer (score 101):

As Egor said, an `int` is just an integer.  Integers don't have leading zeros.  They can only be *displayed* with leading zeros when you convert them to `String` objects.  One way to do that is like this:

```
String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", hrs, mnts);
```

The format string `%02d` formats an integer with leading zeros (that's the `0` in `%02d`), always taking up 2 digits of width (that's the `2` in `%02d`).

That would produce the `String`

> 12:09

Comment: You don't need to be doing the formating yourself on the string. For date handling, use the DateFormat API.

Comment: @Nuno, I didn't say anything about **needing** to do it this way.  When someone starts a sentence with *"One way to do that is ..."*, they are implicitly acknowledging that there are **other** ways to do it.  However, in this case, there is no more work to do it this way (either for the programmer, or for the CPU), vs. using a DateFormatter.  The underlying problem that the poster had was that he/she was not realizing that `int` objects don't have leading zeros.  Only `String` objects would have leading zeros.  My answer explains that, and suggests *one* solution.  That's all.

Answer (score 15):

All is said about integer. But dealing with dates and Calendars to display that information should be used like so:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yourpattern"); //like "HH:mm" or just "mm", whatever you want
String stringRepresentation = sdf.format(date);
```

the pattern "mm" will have a leading zero if it is between 0 and 9. If you use "mmmm" you'll get 0009, which doesn't look like it makes a lot of sense, but it all depends on what you want. :)

if you use pattern `HH:mm` you'll get `12:09` (the current time of your date instance).

Answer (score 5):

You can format date using SimpleDateFormat class

if you are getting date and time from Calendar instance:-

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

timeEdittext.setText(timeFormat.format(c.getTime()));
dateEdittext.setText(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

if you have day, month, year, hour, minute as integer(usually happens in datepicker and timepicker dialogs)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

Used below method to convert `Hour:Minute` in double format.

```
/*
* make double format hour:minute string
* @hour : 1
* @minute : 2
* return : 01:02
* */

public static String hourMinuteZero(int hour,int mnts){
    String hourZero = (hour >=10)? Integer.toString(hour):String.format("0%s",Integer.toString(hour));
    String minuteZero = (mnts >=10)? Integer.toString(mnts):String.format("0%s",Integer.toString(mnts));
    return hourZero+":"+minuteZero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function time()
{
  var time = new Date();
  var hh = time.getHours();
  var mmm = time.getMinutes();

  if(mmm<10) 
  {
    mmm='0'+mmm
  } 

  time = 'T'+hh+':'+mmm;
  return time;
}
```